# In RFID, are there tag modules that give the user a choice of different outputs?

Tags: microcontroller, rfid, microprocessors, circuit, debouncing

I look for an RFID tag that gives you the option to 'choose the output'. For example, you want to choose an RFID-output from a list of X possible outputs using a multi-directional switch with X directions.

Does something like that exist? What resolutions of X are there available? How small can it be?

If not, how could you go about designing the thing? Just slide the antenna over the desired Chip from a number of X chips and do some debouncing? Or use just one chip but connect one out of its X inputs with a further circuit and a debounce?! (and what type of circuit?)

Furthermore, how does one tackle higher resolutions for X without making it bulky (as there is just not enough room to make it work with debouncing and different chips and the mechanics and all)?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities.  One option is to use an RFID/NFC tranceiver like [this](http://www.ti.com/product/TRF7970A/datasheet).  You can lay out a circuit board which can have many dip switches so you can custom configure the value that the RFID chip sends out.  The resolution really depends less on the chip than how many options you want to put on your board. It is difficult to say more without knowing more about the application.